# Reading a movie file in Matlab: The end of file was reached before the requested frames were read completely

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a movie file with .avi extension using mmreader(), it plays the movie but a following warning apperas:

**The end of file was reached before the requested frames were read completely.  Frames 1 through 456 were returned.**

Kindly help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't post the relevant code it is difficult to help you, but I suspect that the problem is with your second input to mmreader. The second input is for specifying what frames to read, and if you specify more frames than the movie file has, you will get that warning.

From the documentation:

> For example, given a file with 2825
>   frames associated with the multimedia
>   object obj, a call to read frames 2800
>   - 3000 as follows:
>
> `images = read(obj, [2800 3000]);`
>
> returns:
>
> Warning: The end of file was reached
>   before the  requested frames were read
>   completely.   Frames 2800 through 2825
>   were returned.

I suggest that you either adjust your second input to mmreader or just ignore the warning, since it shouldn't effect the movie.