# reading video with matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a movie file in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591331/reading-a-movie-file-in-matlab)

I want to read an AVI file with MATLAB but I get an exception:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Here is my code:

```
obj = mmreader('vidd.avi');
a=read(obj);
frames=get(obj,'numberOfFrames');
for k=1:frames-1
    I(k).cdata=a(:,:,:,k);
    I(k).colormap=[];
end
implay(I);
```

Comment: have you googled for the function `aviread`?

Comment: yes but ı take 'Unable to locate decompressor to decompress
video stream' exception

Comment: @MehtapGül: Maybe you'll find an answer for the `aviread` error [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-186ZX/index.html?solution=1-186ZX) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49401).

Comment: @MehtapGül: Try to debug your code. What is the line you got this error?